# How to print values from multiple for loops in Java

Tags: java, for-loop

I wish to create a compound interest calculator that calculates how much money a person would make starting with a sum of $1000 for a time of 15 years. I know how to declare and initialize both variables but don't know how to display the results together.

I think that the problem might have something to do with nested for loops but I can't quite put the pieces together. Does anyone have any ideas?

```
public class tes {    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("NetWorth investing at 15% return per Anum");
        System.out.println("age\t\tInvestment");

        double amount;
        double principle = 100;
        double rate = 0.15;

        for (int age = 23; age < 35; age++) {
            System.out.println(age);
        }

        for (int day = 0; day <= 10; day++) {
            amount= principle * Math.pow(1 + rate, day);
            System.out.println(amount);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you have two `for` loops? Why does neither involve 15 years? Looks like 11 days, and 12 years respectively. Where can I get 115% daily interest?

Comment: Comment/identifier bug: 15% return per Anum, but amount= principle*Math.pow(1+rate, day)? 15% per day? What about interest on interest? And stick to conventions, class name should be Tes. Well, kind of. And where are the 15 years from the introduction? I see 10 and 35-23=12

Answer (score 0):

How about that? Or did i not get your question correctly?

```
for (int age = 23; age < 35; age++) {
 System.out.println(age);

 if (day <= 10) {
  amount = principle * Math.pow(1 + rate, day);
  System.out.println(amount);
  day+=1;
 }
}
```

Comment: My question probably wasn't clear enough. I wanted to print both objects in the same print statement so they were both on the same line.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can gather you would like to display your age next to your investment. In doing this you don't necessarily need the initial loop. We could just initialise your starting age:

```
// the starting age
int age = 23;
for(int year = 0; year<=15; year++) {
    amount= principle*Math.pow(1+rate, year);
    System.out.println(age+year + ":"+ amount);
}
```

So your output should be something similar to this:

```
Age Investment
23 : 100.0
24 : 114.99999999999999
25 : 132.24999999999997
26 : 152.08749999999998
27 : 174.90062499999993
28 : 201.13571874999994
29 : 231.3060765624999
30 : 266.0019880468749
31 : 305.9022862539061
32 : 351.787629191992
33 : 404.5557735707907
34 : 465.23913960640925
35 : 535.0250105473706
36 : 615.2787621294761
37 : 707.5705764488976
38 : 813.7061629162322
```